# jekyll dependency error while read form _post

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm new in Jekyll and I was working fine in my gh-pages Jekyll Project. But when I trying to do post loop from the _posts directory then the following error happened. And I try to resolve this by `gem install redcarpet`  and `gem install rough` but it installs rough successfully. And give an error when trying to install redcarpet.

The Error is:
[image]

And when I use `gem install carpet` it gives me the following error:

[image]

My _posts directory looks like:

[image]

My Operating system is:  Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: this is most probably an issue with the Ruby-2.4.0 bundle you have installed. If you have Ruby `v2.3.1` or `v2.3.2` installed with proper `DevKit` tools for your OS, try installing the gem to the that environment. Alternatively don't use `redcarpet`

Comment: Hey, bro, I never used Ruby before, so can you plz tell me the step. how can I install with proper devkit ????

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `markdown: redcarpet` entry in your `_config.yml` file. It is no longer supported by Jekyll—and isn’t necessary any more.

Comment: Thank you, It solves the problem, but, now it gives me a new warning ...

Building warning: layout 'news' requested in _posts/2017-06-06-work-no-1.md does not exist.